# Any explanation for wrong images showing up?

Tags: xcode, image, resources

Some background. Until I redo this part of the app, for now, I've dragged a bunch of images into my project. They are called Landscapexx.jpg and Portraitxx.jpg, where xx is a number from 0 to the total number of pictures (minus one) for that orientation.

At some point, I replaced the images used in the project. But the original images are still showing up on my device (but not in Xcode). Using NSLog to confirm which image is being loaded, I then look up the image with the same name in Xcode. Sometimes it's the same image. Sometimes it's not.

At first I thought the problem was that when building the app again the data remained. That would be a reasonable explanation. However, when I deleted the app, acknowledging that the data would be deleted, that did not solve the problem. Could this be a cache issue? If so, how do I clear the relevant cache?

One last thing. The images that appear incorrectly on the iPad have the project name checked in the file inspector.

The way I'm loading the images, by the way is using `NSString *newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Landscape%d.jpg",n];`, for example. So the file simply needs to be in my project space somewhere, I thought. If there are two copies, I have no idea where the second one would be. I don't see them in Xcode.

P.S. If I run the app in the simulator, I get the same images as on Xcode. This suggests the errant images are cached somewhere in my iPad. Since deleting the app didn't take care of the problem, is there something else I can try?

EDIT: I found something that may point to an issue. If I go to the Build Phases screen and open the Copy Bundle Resources item, all the images are listed there. However some of them don't have the ...in projectname after them. These same items have the project checked in the file inspector. Not all the images are this way. What do I need to do to ensure all the files are correctly in the project?

Comment: I thought the problem may have been that the app was set up to backup to iCloud. I just turned that off, acknowledged the dialog to delete data from iCloud, then tried running the app again. This time it displayed a bunch of files being copied across that wasn't being done on previous builds. Somehow I need to force the iPad to use the same images as in my project. I'm hoping there's somewhere to force an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Going through all the menu options in Xcode, I found an option called Clean in the Product menu. I selected it, rebuilt the app and all is fine now. This option apparently clears out the precompiled stuff that occurs the first time a project is built.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest deleting the app from the phone, cleaning the project, and rebuilding the app.  This happens to me on occasion and this usually fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that before, but I'd really like to understand what's actually going on.